# CORS issue when connecting Angular project to Laravel backend - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present, but it work in PostMan

Tags: angular, laravel, cors, plesk, access-control

I have a problem and I would like to know where my error is: I want to connect an Angular project to Laravel, but I'm getting this error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://back-domain.com/api/login' from origin 'https://front-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I have this code in the file proyectolaravel/app/Http/Middleware/CORS.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With")
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

In the file proyectolaravel/app/Http/Kernel.php, I have defined the middleware as follows (it is defined 3 times due to different attempts I made):

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    "cors" => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
];
```

And in the file proyectolaravel/routes/api.php, the routes are within the middleware method of the Route class:

```php
Route::middleware(['cors'])->group(function () {
    // protected routes
});
```

I also tried moving the routes outside the middleware method since the middleware is already defined globally.

In the .htaccess file, I have defined the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
</IfModule>
```

The server is running Ubuntu as the operating system and uses Plesk as the server administrator. I have also tried defining the headers for both Nginx and Apache in Plesk, following the steps from this page: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377597400087-How-to-set-up-CORS-cross-origin-resource-sharing-in-Plesk-for-Linux-

However, I am still getting the same CORS error in production.

NOTE: Everything works fine locally (the typical "it works on my machine" situation ), but in production, when testing from PostMan, the server returns the responses correctly, but it does not work from the Angular front-end. I don't have any interceptor in the Angular project to modify the headers, and the services for sending the requests have the following structure:

```js
login(user: ILogin): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return this.http
        .post<IResponse>(`${environment.base_url}/login`, user, {
        headers,
        })
        .pipe(
        map((response) => {
            if (response.head === "success") {
            // calculate token expiration and save it to local storage

            return response;
        })
    );
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could shed some light on where my error might be or what could be causing this CORS problem. Sorry for the "wall of text" and thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Postman isn't blocking CORS requests. Check with your backend to allow cross origins requests.

Comment: try to exclude X-Requested-With and Application from Access-Control-Allow-Headers. I'm using it that way: headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept,Authorization,Content-Type');

Comment: Laravel has built-in cors support, why you write your own?